# Add background image to Rails app when using Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, background-image

I am working on an app using Bootstrap as the framework in Rails (bootstrap-sass). What I want to do is add a sweet background image but I can't seem to override the white background of the body no matter what I try.

Has anyone had success with this? What do I have to change or add to get this to happen?

In addition to trying other things, I have even tried wrapping all the contents in the body in a div with an id, then calling that class in the custom css.scss file where I have successfully customized other aspects of Bootstrap.

The code I added using the id:

```
html body #bgimage {
  background-image: image-url('/images/cityscape.jpg');
}
```

Edit:
I just checked the errors in the development local server and I have this: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/cityscape.jpg"):
/Edit

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a similar discusion recently, the problem was that `background-image` oddly does not work with `bootstrap`. Try:

```
html body #bgimage {
    background: url('cityscape.jpg');
}
```

Notice, that `asset-pipeline` does its work for finding the proper location of your file, so you don't have to mention the path.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. Thank you very much. Now, I can move on to deciding how I want it to look on there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am happy when I can help. Have a nice time with your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your `cityscape.png` is in `assets/images/` directory, please use the following:

```
html body #bgimage {
    background-image: url(image_path('cityscape.jpg'));
}
```

And to use your original source, you have to remove `/images/` from your `image-url` as:

```
html body #bgimage {
  background-image: image-url('cityscape.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just replaced the code with what you have there and it's still not working. For some reason the white background that is default is winning out between the two. The image is in the assets/images directory as it is supposed to be.

Here is a link to my github repository for it:
https://github.com/marcacyr/opinned

Comment: I just checked the errors in the development local server and I have this:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/cityscape.jpg"):